# Ambiguity in the way the Category methods are written to Extend the NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-category

Hi I was going through the AFNetworking Tutorial on Ray Wenderlich blog and in this tutorial project he has written a few categories to extend the NSDictionary and one of the category looks like below:

```
#import "NSDictionary+weather_package.h"

@implementation NSDictionary (weather_package)

- (NSDictionary *)currentCondition
{
    NSDictionary *dict = self[@"data"];
    NSArray *ar = dict[@"current_condition"];
    return ar[0];
}

- (NSDictionary *)request
{
    NSDictionary *dict = self[@"data"];
    NSArray *ar = dict[@"request"];
    return ar[0];
}

- (NSArray *)upcomingWeather
{
    NSDictionary *dict = self[@"data"];
    return dict[@"weather"];
}

@end
```

I know for what the categories are used for in Objective-C. But really the code which he has written seems very high level to me and it's confusing. BTW I'm talking about these lines :

```
NSDictionary *dict = self[@"data"];
NSArray *ar = dict[@"current_condition"];
```

I'm really not understanding how **self[@"data"]** and **dict[@"current_condition"]** work.

So could someone please help me understand what's happening here ? It would be greatly helpful to me.

**PS:** BTW this is how Ray is calling his category method is called on dictionary :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"WeatherCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *daysWeather = nil;

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0: {
            daysWeather = [self.weather currentCondition];
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Question appears to be about objective-c literals not categories. http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/objective-c-literals-part-1/

Comment: Just as a side note, always prefix you category methods with your project prefix, otherwise anyone else who creates another method called `request` will override your method (rather behaviour is going to unpredictable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
NSDictionary *dict = self[@"data"];
```

Is just a nice shortcut for :

```
NSDictionary *dict = [self objectForKey:@"data"];
```

Where the "data" is the key and the value is a `NSDictionary` object.

Same goes with the other line only that the returned value is an array.